# Scala :: TreeMap not balanced after updates?

Tags: scala, immutability, treemap

What am I trying to do is to be able to adjust the key order of an item in TreeMap, so

- I may be able to find an object by some "static" data, which doesn't change
- the position of the object (if the map is flatten) should respect it's "priority"

The following test case works well for **numEntries=6**, but doesn't work for values greater than 7. I don't realy understand what's going wrong there, but I suspect that the tree gets disballanced after some updates/copies. So could somebody please advice - is it my fault or the TreeMap in Scala 2.9 has some sort of bug?

**UPDATE** if the loop

```
for (i <- 1 to (numEntries - 1)) {
```

replaced with

```
for (i <- (numEntries - 1) to 1 by -1) {
```

everything works correctly. So looks like this is the bug in TreeMap?

```
  import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
  import collection.immutable.TreeMap
  import org.junit.runner.RunWith
  import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner

  @RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
  class TreeMapTest extends FlatSpec {

    //val numEntries = 6;
    val numEntries = 10;

    sealed case class Entry(first: Option[Int], last: Int) extends Ordered[Entry] {

      def compare(that: TreeMapTest.this.type#Entry) = {
        if (first.isEmpty || that.first.isEmpty) {
          last compare that.last
        } else {
          (first.get compare that.first.get) match {
            case 0 => last compare that.last
            case x => x
          }
        }
      }

      def increase() = copy(first = Some(this.first.getOrElse(0) + 1))

    }

    type Container = TreeMap[Entry, Entry]

    "TreeMap" should "allow updates" in {
      var dataMap: Container = new Container() ++ (for (i <- 1 to numEntries) yield Entry(Some(0), i) -> Entry(Some(0), i))
      for (i <- 1 to (numEntries - 1)) {
        val key = new Entry(None, i)
        dataMap.get(new Entry(None, i)) match {
          case Some(e) =>
            val newEntry = e.increase()
            dataMap = (dataMap - key) + (newEntry -> newEntry)
          case None => fail("Can not find entry " + key)
        }
      }
    }

  }
```

Comment: Prefer `1 until numEntries` over `1 to (numEntries - 1)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find it extremely unlikely that there's a bug in `TreeMap` basic manipulation -- there were plenty before Scala 2.9.0, but there's now a strong test suite backing `RedBlack`, it's backing store.

More likely, the problem arise of you not having a total order. Say you have three elements:

```
val a = Entry(Some(0), 3)
val b = Entry(Some(1), 0)
val c = Entry(None, 1)
```

Then the following is true:

```
scala> a < b
res39: Boolean = true

scala> b < c
res40: Boolean = true

scala> c < a
res41: Boolean = true
```

So you have a cycle, which means your ordering is not a total ordering. `TreeSet` demands total ordering (in fact, the trait `Ordered` demands total ordering -- there's a specific trait for partial orders).

Let's create two more nodes to show why that can cause problems:

```
val d = Entry(Some(0), 1)
val e = Entry(Some(2), 4)
```

So, d < a < b < e. One possible tree is:

```
      b
     / \ 
    a   e
   /
  d
```

Now, if you try to look up `c` in this tree, you'll first compare `c` with `b`, and find that `c` is bigger than `b`. That means you'll only look on the right branch, that contains `e`, and you'll never find `d`.

Comment: Well, why does it work correctly if I iterate in reverse order then? Also please note, that I don't have items with "None" in the Map itself, it is used only in case if I know the "payload", but have no idea about current "order" of the item. So when I insert something in the map, it has strict and consistent ordering defined.

Comment: It's pure luck that the algorithm picks just the "right" comparisions when going backwards. As Daniel pointed out, your `compare` function is broken, but that doesn't mean that it can't produce correct results under "lucky" circumstances.

Comment: @jdevelop I've put up an example of a valid tree reproducing your problem.